# javascript get input text without any "id", "name", "class"

Tags: javascript

I am trying to capture the text entered in a search box. But the problem is, textbox does not have any id, name or class assigned to it.

This is what it has:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="search text box">
```

So any idea how to capture that value?

Comment: can you share url or complete code

Comment: Is there something surrounding it? I'd guess so, and you can use that as a way to reach it.

Comment: You can either search for the <input> tag inside the <body> tags, or search for it inside a <div> tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it like this assuming the placeholder is unique:

```
let input = document.querySelector("input[placeholder='search text box']");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if(inputs[i].type.toLowerCase() == 'text') {
        alert(inputs[i].value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yay, and now you got *all* the inputs inside a page. Also, `inputs` is what, exactly?